# Eclipse CDT with C running errors

Tags: c, eclipse

so I've decided to install Eclipse to use for my C programming. I wanted to write a small program, just to test that everything works, however it seems that Eclipse won't let me scan in any C inputs. For any other program, that requires no input, it works fine but it seems for some reason Eclipse won't run any program that requires a use to input. I'm running the programs by going to Run->Run As-> Local C/C++ Applications. I've also tried running these programs through the command line, and they turn out fine. Any ideas?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int length, width, height, volume, weight;

    printf("Enter the length of box: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    printf("Enter the height of box: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    printf("Enter the width of box: ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    volume = length * width * height;
    weight = (volume+165)/166;

    printf("Volume(cubic inches) %d\n", volume);
    printf("Dimensional weight(pounds): %d\n", weight);

    return 0;
}
```

Installed Packages:
[image]

After I try to run these programs, nothing appears in the console window, but after I press stop this is what comes out: 
[image]

Here's a better pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugbyP.png

Comment: When you say it won't let your run it, what does it do exactly?

Comment: As in nothing appears in the console window, and then when I press stop a jumble of random integers comes out.

Comment: Did you try typing your input into the console window? That's where it would expect to read the stdin.

Comment: Typing as in just start writing random integers in? The problem is in the console window, it's absolutely blank until I press stop.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `fflush(stdout)` after each of your printf() calls as suggested [here](http://xibaiyu.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/eclipseindigo-with-cdt-no-output-on-console/).

Here is some more discussion of [why fflush is required](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/156519/).